# Jetpack compose - Set Inset padding based on Navigation bar direction

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, windowinsets

For context, I have a UI like this.

[image]  .
[image]

I am making changes for Edge to Edge UI using WindowsInsets following the Android Developers official videos.
[Insets: Compose edition](https://youtu.be/mlL6H-s0nF0)

My use case is I want the content to be visible on the navigation bar when the navigation bar is at the bottom as the navigation bar color is set to transparent as per the [official guidelines](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets).

I have set the navigation bar padding for FloatingActionButton separately.

This UI works for me because I have additional padding at the bottom making all the content scrollable within the visible region. (above transparent nav bar)

But, when the screen is in landscape mode (or in other scenarios where navigation bar appears in the sides),

[image]

Required content is behind the navbar.

**So, how do I apply WindowInset padding for the navigation bar only when the screen is in the sides?**

Code for reference, (Only related code is added to keep it simple)

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    floatingActionButton = {
        FloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.navigationBars),
        )
    },
) {
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            bottom = 80.dp,
        ),
    ) {
        // List UI
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes

Comment: @Injent, Can you add more on how `WindowSize` fits in this use-case?

Comment: with WindowSizeClass determine the size of the screen and display different Composables based on that. For example, if the screen is wide (landscape mode), you show LargeScreen else Default Screen. I'l write example later

Answer (score 2):

Realised I can add a simple orientation check and add padding conditionally.
Still looking for a better solution that is supported directly by WindowInsets or any other features.

Also, there may be scenarios where this may not be correct.

```
val orientation = LocalConfiguration.current.orientation
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    floatingActionButton = {
        FloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.navigationBars),
        )
    },
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.then(
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.navigationBars),
            } else {
                Modifier
            }
        ),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            bottom = 80.dp,
        ),
    ) {
        // List UI
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With WindowSizeClass determine the size of the screen and display different Composables based on that. For example, if the screen is wide (landscape mode), you show LargeScreen else Portrait Screen:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenRoute(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass // from activity calculateWindowSizeClass(activity)
) {
    if (windowSizeClass.widthSizeClass == WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact) {
        Screen()
    } else {
        Screen(Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.navigationBars))
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

}
```

Read more in this [article](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/windowsizeclass/package-summary)

Note: it also let you create Composable screens for all screen sizes

Comment: Changing the layout based on screen width does not solve the problem. There are Android devices that have more width than height even in portrait mode.

Comment: @Abhimanyu You are wrong. There is no android device in the whole world where in portrait mode the width is bigger than the height. So my solution has a right to be. I'm using the solution that google provided to the developers, I think they've thought of everything. Otherwise I've seen your solution, I think it's good too.

Comment: "You are wrong. There is no android device in the whole world where in portrait mode the width is bigger than the height". Wow, so nice response, directly assumed I am wrong with so much confidence. There are so many Android device models. There are foldable, tabs, and Windows has resizable Android app support.

Comment: @Abhimanyu When your application is in single-screen mode in a foldable device, it will always have a height greater than width in portrait mode. and even if it is not in single-screen mode, but in dual-screen, multi-window, or spanned, each window will have its own orientation. And judging by the sources I looked at about determining the screen orientation in multi-window mode, the orientation is set there automatically based on the width and height of the window. That is, if the window is wide, it will be landscape mode. So check the information before making conclusions